# Set user text in div and preventing XSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss

I have a textbox in which user type his email address.
When he clicks "space" key, I create a new div with this text.

The problem is that the user can type: `<script>alert(1);</script>` for example, and if I use `$('#textbox').val()` the script is running.

so I tried to use jquery `.html()` and give encoded string, but it doesn't work in chrome, firefox and old versions of IE.

How can I prevent the script from running and set user value to the div?

Comment: As long as you don't save it in the Database and share it with other visitors, XSS is no problem.

Comment: use `.text`: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/t2Cvn/

Comment: @abhitalks Arh - I should learn to click on my own links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `jquery.text()` if you want to escape tags in the entered input.

```
var t = $('#textbox').val();
$('#div1').text(t);
```

Comment: I tried, but I get empty value. only $('#textbox').val() returns the user's value.

Comment: var t = $('#textbox').val(); $('#div1').text(t);

Comment: Thanks! I created the div dynamically: $('#recipients_area_input').before('<span class="recipient" title="' + value + '"><div class="email_address">' + value + '</div><a class="del_recipient"></a></span>'); so i changed it and put the values after the creation and it works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery's .text method will return only text without HTML tags

```
$("#textbox").text();
```